# Change Joomla module front end code

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I want to edit the `HTML` output that a particular module is rendering in the module's `tmpl/default.php` file. I located the file on the FTP, made the changes, and nothing is being conveyed when I clear the cache and browse to the page where I should see the difference.

Not sure what I'm missing here. Joomla 2.5.7.

Comment: check whether the following file have edit permission in ftp.

Comment: There is no Joomla 2.5.8?? Latest is currently 2.5.7!

Answer (score 3):

You should never edit the modules built n `tmpl/default.php` file. Doing so will likely result in the edits being overwritten when you update the module.

@Jobin Jose is on the right track with #4 for both the answer to your query as well as the correct way to change the HTML output of a module.

First, make a copy of `your_module/tmpl/default.php`

Next, save that copy in `templates/your_template/html/your_module/default.php`

Make all the edits you want to that copy of the file, it will not be touched when you update the module later.

Comment: This can be marked as answer. Editing .php file directly in <mod_> folder will not change anything. You need to override the module and edit the new file usually located in template/<theme>/html/<mod_>

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure the following things

1. you have permission to edit the file in FTP.
2. No cache plugin is enabled.
3. the right module tmpl/default.php is editing.
4. Make sure its not overrided(If it is overrided then you can found the html of module inside your template folder.)

Comment: I do have permission to edit via FTP.

Comment: Apparently the site root is under a different path. I was editing the file in the wrong path. I am sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: Really, seriously, do not edit the file, copy the file as Brent explained.